# MySQLi error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli, error-log

Is it possible to specify that MySQLi sends any errors and warnings to the PHP default 'error_log' directive? I can't seem to find any error options for the class specification, and I don't wish to handle errors manually like so:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("...")) {  }
else
    handle $mysqli->error;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one way would be to override the class:

```
class myMySQLi extends MySQLi {

    public function query($query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
        $res = parent::query($query, $resultmode);
        if (!$res) {
            //handle error
        }
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Then just use as normal, except instead of creating an connection via `new MySQLi()`, use `new myMySQLi()`.  Other than the error handling, it'll run just the same. I do this quite often, to throw exceptions on errors and to add additional functionality to MySQLi...

Comment: hi there thanks for your reply. I suppose I could do that if it's the only option, but it seems odd to me that an error generated by the mysqli ctor can be logged to the default error_log, but any errors that occur while using the mysqli object have to be manually handled!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is possible. All you have to do is enable automatic error reporting and tell PHP to log all errors into a file.

Before you open a connection using mysqli you should ensure that you have these two settings enabled:

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1); // this can be set in INI file too, together with error_log path
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', /** ... */);
```

You don't need to check for mysqli errors manually anymore and all errors will be logged to a file.