# Is there a way to attach an event handler function to mysql errors?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Currently, my best way of handling mysql errors is to add this after every mysql statement:

```
if($mysqli->error)
errorhandlingfunction();
```

Is there a way to create a type of handler for mysql errors and assign a function every time there is an error instead of having to manually check each time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQLi error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932113/mysqli-error-handling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class that extends `mysqli` and throws an exception when an error occurs:

```
/* Create custom exception classes */
class ConnectException extends Exception {}
class QueryException extends Exception {}

class Mysqlie extends mysqli
{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::init();
    if (!parent::options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'set session sql_mode="strict_all_tables";')) {
        throw new ConnectException("Cannot set MySQL options");
    }

    $args = func_get_args();
    $result = call_user_func_array("parent::real_connect", $args);
   /* Pass all arguments passed to the constructor on to the parent's constructor */
    if (!$result) {
        throw new ConnectException('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }

  }

  function query($query)
  {
    $result = parent::query($query);
    if(mysqli_error($this)){
      throw new QueryException(mysqli_error($this), mysqli_errno($this));
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
try {
  $conn = new mysqlie(...connection parameters...);
  $result = $conn->query("MyQuery");

  // do lots more stuff here
  // including more queries
  $result = $conn->query("MyNextQuery");

  // finally close...
  $conn->close();


} catch (ConnectException $e)) {
   die("Can't connect to database".$e->getMessage());
} catch (QueryException $e) {
   die("Query error:".$e->getMessage());
}
```

The content of your `try` block could obviously be much larger and include multiple queries.

Comment: How might I add a function to catch parameterized statements?

Comment: Further extend the class to include `prepare`, `bind` and `execute` methods that override the parent methods. Add new Exceptions similar to those I added here (ExecuteException, perhaps). Trap any errors in the class and `throw` one of your new exceptions. You can add as many `catch` blocks as you need, each trapping different Exceptions.